# How do I query array element in impala?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I created a table in `impala` ,the have two columns ,

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+
| name      | type                | comment |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+
| unique_id | string              |         |
| cmap      | array<struct<       |         |
|           |   fieldname:string, |         |
|           |   fieldid:string,   |         |
|           |   fielddata:string  |         |
|           | >>                  |         |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+
```

i need set the conditions for cmap to query unique_id, such as

```
(fieldname="ip"and fielddata="192.168.1.145") and(fieldname="wid" and fielddata="15")
```

i wrote this sql but can't query it, but i inserted the data in the table

sql：

```
select unique_id  from s_click_parquet,s_click_parquet.cmap as lst  where ( fieldname="ip" and fieldData="192.168.1.145") and(fieldname="wid" and fielddata="15");
```

Comment: unique_Id  string,  cmap array<struct<fieldname:string,fieldid:string,fielddata:string>>    there are table columns describe

Answer (score 0):

You typically access arrays with square brackets, but you can have an array of structs, not just an array.

You can `INLINE()` an array of struct to make it multiple rows, as well as splitting the fields to queryable columns.

Then you can query it as you would a normal table.

Play around with

```
select * 
    from table1 t
       lateral view inline(cmap) a;
```

Comment: `lateral view` is support in impala?I didn't find in document

Comment: It actually says it's not supported https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_complex_types.html#complex_types

Answer (score 0):

*From my work collogue:
so rule of thumb is structs can get accessed via strucName.*, while arrays have to be joined*

So if we have the following types from an avro schema:

```
case class Visit (var Patient: PatientType = null)

case class PatientType(
    var Name: String = null,
    var Address: List[AddressType] = null
    )
    
case class AddressType(
    var Line1: String = null,
    var Line2: String = null,
    var City: String = null,
    var State: String = null,
    var ZipCode: String = null
    )
```

You would query for patient name and address like:

```
select vis.patient.name, addr.item.* 
from visit vis
left join vis.patient.address addr
```